# How to select a browser tab from another tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to select a browser tab from another tab. For example one of my web app is opened in a browser and I opened a link in another tab. Now I want to select my first tab using a shortcut key like "CTRL+M" or something like that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to select anything outside your HTML-structure programmatically. The only option you have, is to close the current tab so it *may* jump back to the last tab:

```
window.close();
```

Even this approach is based on some assumptions and unreliable. Don't go that way ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this only works if one of the tabs is a popup of another tab. Then you can use

```
window.opener.focus();
```

To focus the tab that opened the pop up
and

```
popupName.focus();
```

To focuse the pop up